# Sequential signals between two processes

Tags: c, linux, signals, ipc, sigprocmask

I have a parent process and two children. The parent process only creates two children, a reader and a counter, and waits for its death.  The children do the following things.

The first child (reader):

1. opens file,
2. reads a line,
3. sends a signal (SIGUSR1) to the second child,
4. waits for a signal from the second child,
5. go to 2 if we can read another line, else kill the second child.

The second child (counter):

1. waits for a signal (SIGUSR1) from reader,
2. counts line length,
3. sends a signal to reader and go to 1.

I have trouble waiting for a signal from another process.  The signal can be received before I call `pause()` function, i.e., process can be blocked forever. I also tried to use `sigprocmask()`, `sigsuspend()` and `sigwaitinfo()`, but it doesn't work correctly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_LEN = 16 };

void handler(int signo)
{
    // do nothing
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    sigset_t ss;
    sigemptyset(&ss);
    sigaddset(&ss, SIGUSR1);

    // handle SIGUSR1
    signal(SIGUSR1, handler);

    // shared memory for file line
    char *data = mmap(NULL, MAX_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

    pid_t *pid_counter = mmap(NULL, sizeof(*pid_counter), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

    pid_t pid_reader;
    if (!(pid_reader = fork())) {
        sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &ss, NULL);
        printf("READER: waiting signal from COUNTER\n"); fflush(stdout);
        sigwaitinfo(&ss, NULL);
        sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &ss, NULL);
        printf("READER: got signal\n"); fflush(stdout);

        printf("READER: opening file\n"); fflush(stdout);
        FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        while (fgets(data, MAX_LEN, f) > 0) {
            printf("READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER\n"); fflush(stdout);

            sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &ss, NULL);
            kill(*pid_counter, SIGUSR1);
            sigwaitinfo(&ss, NULL);
            sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &ss, NULL);

            printf("READER: got signal\n"); fflush(stdout);
        }
        printf("READER: closing file and killing COUNTER\n"); fflush(stdout);
        fclose(f);
        kill(*pid_counter, SIGTERM);
        _exit(0);
    }

    if (!(*pid_counter = fork())) {
        sleep(1);
        printf("COUNTER: send signal to READER that COUNTER is ready\n"); fflush(stdout);
        while (1) {
            sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &ss, NULL);
            kill(pid_reader, SIGUSR1);
            printf("COUNTER: waiting signal from READER\n"); fflush(stdout);
            sigwaitinfo(&ss, NULL);
            sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &ss, NULL);
            printf("COUNTER: got signal\n"); fflush(stdout);

            printf("%d\n", strlen(data));
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

For this code I can get the following sequence:

```
$ gcc -o prog prog.c && ./prog input.dat
READER: waiting signal from COUNTER
COUNTER: send signal to READER that COUNTER is ready
COUNTER: waiting signal from READER
READER: got signal
READER: opening file
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
READER: got signal
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
READER: got signal
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
READER: got signal
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
READER: got signal
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
READER: got signal
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
READER: got signal
READER: closing file and killing COUNTER
```

Why counter doesn't write "got signal"? How I can send and receive signals synchronously? (I know about other IPC methods, but I need synchronization through signals.)

Comment: Perhaps [`sigwaitinfo`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigwaitinfo) is what you want: "sigwaitinfo() suspends execution of the calling thread until one of the signals in set is pending (If one of the signals in set is already pending for the calling thread, sigwaitinfo() will return immediately.)".

Comment: @kaylum, there is a problem. `kill(pid_reader, SIGUSR1)` runs reader process which can send signal before `sigwaitinfo()` will be executed by counter process.

Comment: As described by the man page referenced: "If one of the signals in set is already pending for the calling thread, sigwaitinfo() will return immediately.". That is, the signal can be sent before calling `sigwaitinfo`. It will still work.

Comment: @kaylum, I edited post. May be I do something wrong?

Comment: I suspect you are not characterising the problem correctly. It's not really the fact that the signal is sent before `pause/sigwaitinfo` is called. Because that should work for `sigwaitinfo` as I have repeatedly pointed out. It looks more like your problem is that the signal is sent *before the second process is created* or *before the second process has set up its signal handling*. To guarantee that both processes are ready you need another form of synchronisation to make both processes wait until the other process is ready.

Comment: @kaylum, I edited post again. Now here is example of my program. You can run it several times and see results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few obvious problems here.

The one that is actually causing your issue is this:

```
if (!(*pid_counter = fork())) {
```

Remember that (1) `pid_counter` points to shared memory; and (2) `fork()` returns *twice* every time it is called. When it returns in the child, it will set `*pid_counter` to `0`, but when it returns in the parent, it'll set `*pid_counter` to the PID of the child. You cannot predict which will happen first. What's actually going on in your case is that it ends up set to `0`, and so all your `kill` calls in the reader process are sending signals to every process in your process group, so both reader and counter are getting them at the same time. This is causing your synchronization to fail, because both processes are returning from `sigwaitinfo()` at the same time. In the reader, you should send `SIGUSR1` to the counter process only.

What you need to do is change it to this:

```
pid_t temp_pid
if ( !(temp_pid = fork()) ) {
    *pid_counter = getpid();
```

Other points:

1. `sigprocmask()` is preserved across `fork()` calls, so you should just set it once before `fork()`ing. You never need to unblock it in your case, and should not.
2. There is no need to (and arguably better not to) establish a handler for `SIGUSR1` if you're calling `sigwaitinfo()` on it.
3. `strlen()` returns type `size_t`, so your `printf()` format specifier should be `%zu`, not `%d`.
4. All your calls to `fflush(stdout)`, while harmless, are here superfluous.
5. You hardly ever check any of the returns from your system calls. This is not just for production code - if your program is not working, the very first thing to do it verify that you're checking all your system calls for success, because the reason it may not be working is because one of those calls is failing, perhaps because you passed it bad information. It's more important to check for success when you are testing your program, not less important.

Anyway, here's a working version of your program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

enum { MAX_LEN = 16 };

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    if ( argc != 2 ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Enter one argument, and one argument only.\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // shared memory for file line
    char *data = mmap(NULL, MAX_LEN, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED |
                      MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
    if ( data == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("mmap() failed for data");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t *pid_counter = mmap(NULL, sizeof *pid_counter, PROT_READ |
                              PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
    if ( pid_counter == MAP_FAILED ) {
        perror("mmap() failed for pid_counter");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pid_t pid_reader, temp_pid;

    sigset_t ss;
    sigemptyset(&ss);
    sigaddset(&ss, SIGUSR1);
    if ( sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &ss, NULL) == -1 ) {
        perror("sigprocmask() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( (pid_reader = fork()) == -1 ) {
        perror("fork() failed for reader");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if ( !pid_reader ) {
        printf("READER: waiting signal from COUNTER\n");

        if ( sigwaitinfo(&ss, NULL) == -1 ) {
            perror("sigwaitinfo() failed in reader");
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("READER: got signal\n");

        printf("READER: opening file\n");

        FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if ( !f ) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't open input file\n");
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while ( fgets(data, MAX_LEN, f) ) {
            printf("READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER\n");

            if ( kill(*pid_counter, SIGUSR1) == -1 ) {
                perror("kill() for SIGUSR1 failed in reader");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            if ( sigwaitinfo(&ss, NULL) == -1 ) {
                perror("sigwaitinfo() failed in reader");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            printf("READER: got signal\n");
        }
        printf("READER: closing file and killing COUNTER\n");
        fclose(f);
        if ( kill(*pid_counter, SIGTERM) == -1 ) {
            perror("kill() for SIGTERM failed in reader");
            _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if ( (temp_pid = fork()) == -1 ) {
        perror("fork() failed for counter");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else if ( temp_pid == 0 ) {
        *pid_counter = getpid();

        sleep(1);
        printf("COUNTER: send signal to READER that COUNTER is ready\n");

        while (1) {
            if ( kill(pid_reader, SIGUSR1) == -1 ) {
                perror("kill() failed for SIGUSR1 in counter");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            printf("COUNTER: waiting signal from READER\n");

            if ( sigwaitinfo(&ss, NULL) == -1 ) {
                perror("sigwaitinfo() failed in counter");
                _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }

            printf("COUNTER: got signal\n");

            printf("%zu\n", strlen(data));
        }

        _exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }

    if ( wait(NULL) == -1 ) {
        perror("first wait() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if ( wait(NULL) == -1 ) {
        perror("second wait() failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

with the following output for the shown file:

```
paul@thoth:~/src$ cat file.txt
line one
line two
line three

paul@thoth:~/src$ ./sig file.txt
READER: waiting signal from COUNTER
COUNTER: send signal to READER that COUNTER is ready
COUNTER: waiting signal from READER
READER: got signal
READER: opening file
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
COUNTER: got signal
9
COUNTER: waiting signal from READER
READER: got signal
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
COUNTER: got signal
9
COUNTER: waiting signal from READER
READER: got signal
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
COUNTER: got signal
11
COUNTER: waiting signal from READER
READER: got signal
READER: reading line and waiting signal from COUNTER
COUNTER: got signal
1
COUNTER: waiting signal from READER
READER: got signal
READER: closing file and killing COUNTER
paul@thoth:~/src$
```

Comment: Excellent comment, thank you! I don't know how I can forget about return value of `fork()`.